# Pubnub Access Management with Python

Tags: python, django, webserver, real-time, pubnub

I am trying to use Pubnub Access Management with Python by I always get an error message saying that the 'Signature Does not Match'. I know their documentation says that this means that the Secret/Publish/Subscribe keys may be wrong but I have triple checked that they are correct. Also checked in Pubnub developer console and it works fine from there.

Here is the method that I am using:

```
def get_pubnub_token(request, connector_id):
    pubnub = Pubnub(settings.PUBKEY, settings.SUBKEY, secret_key=settings.PUB_SECRET_KEY)
    authkey = str(uuid.uuid4())
    result = pubnub.grant(channel=connector_id+"-pnpres", auth_key=authkey, read=True, write=True, ttl=60)
    if result['error']:
        return HttpResponse(status=result['status'])
    result = pubnub.grant(channel=connector_id, auth_key=authkey, read=True, write=True, ttl=60)
    if result['error']:
        return HttpResponse(status=result['status'])
    result = pubnub.grant(channel=connector_id+"-stream", auth_key=authkey, read=True, write=True, ttl=60)
    if result['error']:
        return HttpResponse(status=result['status'])
    jsonstr = get_json(authkey)
    return HttpResponse(jsonstr, content_type='application/json')
```

I wonder if anyone has done this before and if they could give me any tips as to why I could be seeing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were problems using version 3.7.1 of the SDK in python 3.4.3. They were addressed by Pubnub's developers some time last night and it seems to have been resolved in their development code. I guess they will put it into the production code some time in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the SDK are you on?

Also, this may also happen because your system clock is not set to NTP. Can you verify its set to NTP, and try again?

If it persists, please contact us at support@pubnub.com and we'd be happy to help trace the issue down with you.

geremy

Comment: I am using version 3.7.1 of the SDK in python 3.4.3.

Comment: I am developing on a macbook pro. How do I check if the clock is set to NTP?

Comment: Date and Time Preferences -> "Set date and time automatically"

Comment: If the NTP trick doesnt work, ping us at support@pubnub.com and we'll work together to figure it out.

Comment: There were problems using version 3.7.1 of the SDK in python 3.4.3. They were addressed by Pubnub's developers some time last night and it seems to have been resolved in their development code. I guess they will put it into the production code some time in the near future.

Comment: Its in the development branch now but will be in pip/master by next week, pending our testing/deploy process. If you have a need for it beforehand and have issues getting it, drop us a line at support@pubnub.com and we'll help you out.